# Passing Variables from PHP to another PHP with $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I'm having a problem passing a variable from one PHP file to another PHP file. I'm trying to send the varialbe $insert to another PHP file that will just display it. For the life of me, I can't figure out why it won't work.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

1st PHP File (Sending $insert to $_SESSION['finalimage'])

```
<?php

 session_start();
 $insert = rand(5, 1500);
 $_SESSION['finalimage'] = $insert;

 header("Location: http://www.shmoggo.com/snapshot/snapshot_view.php");

 echo base64_decode($_POST["image"]);

 $final = base64_decode($_POST["image"]);


 $newpath = "uploads/" . $insert . ".jpg"; 
 file_put_contents($newpath, $final);

 ?>
```

2nd PHP File (Receiving $insert from $_SESSION['finalimage'])

```
 <?php

 session_start();
 $insert = $_SESSION['finalimage'];
 echo "Image Number = ". $insert;

 ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work", exactly?

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: Are both of these pages on the same domain?

Comment: why are you executing any code after redirection? You should always `exit()` after `header("Location:`

Comment: Might want to verify that the session ID (get it via `session_id()`) is the same on both pages. If it's not, you've got at least 2 different sessions in use, and the one on your 2nd page is empty/new.

Comment: Are they both under the same domain?

Comment: The $insert variable doesn't seem to pass. The 2nd PHP echoes "Image Number = " It's blank..

Comment: @MarcB Thank you! I set the ID's to be the same and it worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: heh, you shouldn't need to set the session ids to be the same. if you are doing this manually, are you setting every user that visits your page to have the same session id? if so, this means that all session variables will be the same for every user that visits your site, which kind of defeats the purpose of sessions.

Comment: @dqhendricks Thanks for the tip, do you happen to know what would remedy the situation?

Comment: When you do session_start(), if a session id already exists for that user, it will be used, if not, one is generated and used from then forward. I cannot imagine what would cause two different session ids to be generated for the same user, unless the request was coming from two different places, or the user had cookies disabled or something.

Comment: what is the output of print_r($_SESSION) on both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check is how your PHP installation is supporting sessions.  There are two possible methods for "persisting" the session ID between requests:

1) using cookies or
2) using "URL rewriting" (ie each URL passes a sessionid value)

If you are using cookies check to see if your server is in fact sending a cookie to your browser.

If you are using url-rewriting the Location header that you are sending that re-routes the client browser to "snapshot_view.php" will need to be modified to include the session id.  Like this:

```
$reroute = 'Location: http://www.shmoggo.com/snapshot/snapshot_view.php?PHPSESSID=' . session_id();
header($reroute);
```

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you. FireFox isn't enabling cookies to allow the cookie method to work. I can't figure out how to use this code you gave me to do that same thing with cookies... any wise words?

Comment: Hi Aaron -- if you were using a cookie to persist the session ID at the browser then the above code would not be necessary because the cookie is automatically sent in with each request. URL rewriting does not depend on cookie support but it means that every URL must include the PHPSESSID value - PHP will look after **most** of these for you automatically but when sending out a "Location" header you must do this manually.

PS in your original code you should probably move the "Header()" call to the end of the code to avoid get back a request before the image file has been committed to disk.